# Why do unregistered filters get called anyway?

Tags: spring, filter, spring-security

I've two Spring Security filters annotated with @Component and extending OncePerRequestFilter.
The problem is, I don't register them with httpSecurity while configuration, but they still get called.
**I want to call these two filters based on mvc matchers and not shouldNotFilter() method.**
My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private InitialAuthenticationFilter initialAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;


    @Autowired
    private OtpAuthenticationProvider otpAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private EmailPasswordAuthenticationProvider emailPasswordAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {

        builder.authenticationProvider(emailPasswordAuthenticationProvider)
               .authenticationProvider(otpAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();


    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

The two filters

```
@Component
public class InitialAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;

    @Value("${authentication.jwtSigningKey}")
    private String jwtSigningKey;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Init filter is trying to authenticate");

        String email = request.getHeader("email");
        String password = request.getHeader("password");
        String code = request.getHeader("code");

        if (code == null || code.isEmpty()) {

            manager.authenticate(
                    new EmailPasswordAuthentication(email, password)
            );
        }
        else {

            OtpAuthentication otpAuthentication = new OtpAuthentication(email, code);
            manager.authenticate(otpAuthentication);

            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                    jwtSigningKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            );

            String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
                                  .setClaims(Map.of("email", email))
                                  .signWith(key)
                                  .compact();

            response.setHeader("Authorization", jwtToken);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {

        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/login");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${authentication.jwtSigningKey}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("JWT filter is trying to authenticate");

        String jws = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (jws == null || jws.isEmpty()) {

            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
            return;
        }

        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                            .setSigningKey(key)
                            .build()
                            .parseClaimsJws(jws)
                            .getBody();

        String email = String.valueOf(claims.get("email"));

        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user");

        EmailPasswordAuthentication authentication =
                new EmailPasswordAuthentication(
                    email,
                    null,
                    List.of(authority)
                );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return request.getServletPath().equals("/login");
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

There is not JWT filter here, but still it gets called

```
JWT filter is trying to authenticate
```

Comment: Because any `javax.servlet.Filter` in the application context will automatically be registered as filters in the filter chain (**not** the security filter chain!). If you add them again to the security filter chain they will be invoked twice .

Comment: Thank you for that, now I see why it gets called twice.
Do you know how can I integrate a filter of type ```javax.servlet.Filter``` into my system the proper way so it doesn't get included in non-security-related filter chain and I can filter requests based on mvc mathcers?

Comment: Add a `FilterRegistrationBean` for this filter and set the `enabled` property to `false`.